# MySQL: is primary key unique by default?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, unique-key

If I define a column as a *primary key* in MySQL, is it also *unique key* by default or do I need to also define it as *unique key* (in case I want it to be unique)?

I saw this question [What is the difference b/w Primary Key and Unique Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973420/what-is-the-difference-b-w-primary-key-and-unique-key) that explain the difference between the two, but doesn't exactly answer my question.

Does PK is UK by default or I need to explicitly define it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference b/w Primary Key and Unique Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973420/what-is-the-difference-b-w-primary-key-and-unique-key)

Comment: @Akhil - I saw this question in the link, that explain the difference between the two but doesn't exactly answer my question. does PK is UK by default or I need to explicitly define it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between primary key and unique key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565996/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[Primary key is always unique](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/primary-key-optimization.html) in every SQL. You dont have to explicitly define it as UNIQUE.

**On a side note:** You can only have onePrimary key in a table and it never allows null values. Also you can have only one primary key constraint in the table(as the point of creating a primary key is to uniquely identify the row in your table) but you can more than one unique key constraint in your table.

**Example:**

An employee details table having EmpID as Primary key and EmpPhoneNo as unique key.

Comment: another point : a table can have **only one PRIMARY KEY** constraint but it can have as many as you want UNIQUE KEY constraints

Comment: Actually there are more differences between unique and primary key, like primary key cannot be NULL. But that's not the question about.

Comment: "On a side note: You can only have onePrimary key in a table" what about composite primary key?

Comment: It's still one Primary Key, @AraYeressian.

Answer (score 9):

Primary key is always unique by definition. Not only in MySQL.
So you don't need any additional unique key.

Answer (score 4):

Note that composite keys may lead to confusion : indeed a primary key can be a composite key, and `DESCRIBE` will show all of the composite key components as primary keys :

```
> DESCRIBE foobar;
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| column_A             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| column_B             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

However `SHOW CREATE TABLE` will show the reality :

```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE foobar;
+--------+---------------------------…+
| Table  | Create Table              …|
+--------+---------------------------…+
| foobar | CREATE TABLE `foobar` (
  `column_A` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `column_B` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`column_A`,`column_B`),
  KEY `column_B` (`column_B`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+--------+---------------------------…+
```