# How to set arbitrary id-like key?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I set something like `id` which would be unique and generated after creating an object?

I would like to assign identifier for each object so `user` can indentify product by this id but I don't want it to be regular autoincrement id because I want it let's say consists of 10 digit. (my pk's are `1,2...inf`).

What I've done so far is that I've tried to create a hash of the name but it's not a good way to do that.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    job_id = models.BigIntegerField() # or hash(something)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders', help_text=_("Customer"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    translator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='jobs', null=True, blank=True, help_text=_(u"Translator"))
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=_(u"Price"))
```

One possible way would be to create a `post_save` `signal` which would generate random 10 digit number and then check for uniqueness but it's probably very consuming solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) instead:

> A field for storing universally unique identifiers. Uses Python’s UUID
>   class. When used on PostgreSQL, this stores in a uuid datatype,
>   otherwise in a char(32).
>
> Universally unique identifiers are a good alternative to AutoField for
>   primary_key. The database will not generate the UUID for you, so it is
>   recommended to use default:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # other fields
```

You didn't mentioned used RDMBS, but PostgreSQL has better support for UUID, you can read more [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-uuid.html).

Comment: Thanks, since project is in progress, I don't want to mess id's and uuid. I want just not PK, unique, identifier for users. So do I have to change primary_key to unique?

Comment: I don't get it. You asked about alternative, here it is. Primary key is always unique, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911898/mysql-is-primary-key-unique-by-default).

Comment: Mixing both is not recommended. It's better to use either id or uuid.